Is this the end for the hard-working freshers in tech industry?
I feel like there is no hope this time for freshers in the tech industry, especially international students, doesn't matter if you are a hard-working person.
If you don't have much experience and didn't graduate from a well-known college, it's tough to get into an interview without referrals (I have been applying to hundreds of companies from start-ups to medium-sized companies, this is an advantage of local folks). If you cannot finish the LeetCode coding questions immediately during the coding interview even though you know it will work, it's over.
The 2023-2024 job market is extremely different.

VTC - this sort of question is going to be highly opinion based, and as such, of limited value here.

"I am a very hard-working person, willing to sleep only 2-3 hours every day in a year just to get every task done on time" That is simply not possible, so I question the veracity and intention of your question, and even if it is possible, it is decidedly unhealthy, and likely to result in impaired judgement and performance. You're not hardworking, you're working yourself to death and probably not even aware of your atrocious performance as a result. If you really don't sleep a lot, and only work-work-work, it likely shows in your interviews, resulting in rejection.

If you really needed to sleep 3 hours per day for a whole year to get things done, either your manager was terrible at assigning tasks or you have terrible planning skills.

Consider finding a mentor. Someone that help you understand the industry that you want to join. You've described coding / coders more like something out of a crappy movie than a profession. For example: I was interviewing C# devs a month ago. One of them asked how we handle "Crunch time". I didn't consider that person. Why should be acceptable shove product out the door with poor procedures / planning?

" international student": Do you require a sponsorship for a visa or a permit to work in the US ?

“willing to sleep only 2-3 hours every day in a year” - This isn’t a positive trait, I would not select a potential employee, who doesn’t understand that their willingness to work 22 hours a day is a negative not a positive.

@Hilmar Willing to bet that is likely. Which does make the job market very difficult for him... Not many companies are willing to hire someone who needs a visa when they could hire someone who doesn't need one.... With the exception of a couple of well known companies, but I heard a rumor that was because it allowed them to mistreat their international staff because so few companies want the hassle of an international hire.


You have very little real experience.

You've had a single interview.

Based on your lack of success landing a job, your attitude is "We're all doomed."


Give it time, keep applying, and keep interviewing.

My expectation is that I will need to submit many resumes to get a single interview and then anywhere from 10 to 20 interviews in order to get a job. The OP needs to keep working to get interviews.
